# Insert a document with Flask-PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I have a MongoDB database and I want to use Flask-PyMongo to work with it in my Flask app.  How do I add a database and a collection so I can add user documents?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'microblogdb'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://briangunsel:password@microblog:27017/microblogdb'
mongo = PyMongo(app, config_prefix='MONGO')


@app.route('/')
def home():
    posts = mongo.db.posts.find({})
    return render_template('users.html', posts=posts)

app.run(debug=True)
```

Update:
With only that code above, when I start up the server (python **init**.py) and I go to load the web page, it loads for about 10 seconds and then gives me this error https://gist.github.com/anonymous/62ca41e98e67b304838d. I am running the database `microblogdb` in another cmd prompt, and I set the mongo --dbpath to \data\, which is a folder I created in the microblog folder. Through the mongo interpreter, I added a `posts` collection, it is still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mongo.db.users`](http://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask_pymongo.wrappers.Database) returns the users collection on the database you [configured](http://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#configuration).  Flask-PyMongo is using the PyMongo driver, which has extensive documentation.  PyMongo's [tutorial](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#inserting-a-document) explains how to insert a document.  You already have code that fetches the users who have `online=True`.

```
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://username:password@host:port/db_name'
```

```
user_id = mongo.db.users.insert_one({'name': 'david'}).inserted_id
```